# what are the mathematical formulas/concepts used in implementing Chart API (bar chart, pie chart etc.,)

Tags: java

Trying to implement chart API in Java. But I am unsure of the mathematical formulas/concepts used in drawing each of the chart type. Can someone specify the mathematical concepts to be known for drawing each sort of the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm... very general question, so I can only answer equally general:

Take a look at **[gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/)**, which is a great mathematical plotting/charting api.

You can find out its **concepts** by looking at some [plots](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category%3aGnuplot_diagrams) and the [manual](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.4/gnuplot.pdf), the corresponding **formulas** by reading the [source code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/4.4.3/gnuplot-4.4.3.tar.gz/download?_test=goal).